# NUnit adding info to tests

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

What should I do if I want to show some additional info during the test?

Say I test an algorithm that tries to find a root of a function on the given interval and I want the test to also show the number of iterations it did.

I can add `Assert.Inconclusive(_iterations.ToString())` to the end of each test, but that doesn't look good/green.

Comment: If you have a performance requirement, why don't you just assert this requirement. If you do not, then why do you want to know the number of iterations?

Comment: because I want to compare them across different implementations

Answer (score 1):

Use `Trace.WriteLine()`. That shows up in your build log.

However, you state "Say **I test** an algorithm that tries to find a root of a function on the given interval **and I want the test** to also show the number of iterations it did."

This means you are testing two things. Regardless if you want these two assertions in one test or two, you should still -test- them if that is your goal, not use `Trace.WriteLine()`. (You are secretly testing!)

Comment: I may be secretely testing them, but it's really obscure because I don't have a requirement on that number, just a variable to keep in mind as it's hardly even comparable between implementations. Thanks for the Trace.WriteLine().

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your test runner you could write info to the console using `Console.WriteLine()`. If you run your tests from command line (nunit-console) this will make it messy while using ReSharper it will look ok.